# Use of matplotlib.animation with wxmplot

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am newbie in python GUI programming and i am interested to learn about using  using matplotlib.animation with wxmplot. Any direction is appreciated.

Comment: @QiaSam, did you look at the wxPython demo?

Comment: @Igor, I went through many examples of using wxPython including drawing charts. I am looking for a way to examples to animate charts using matplotlib.animation in a wxPython frame.

Comment: There is an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579658/embedding-a-live-updating-matplotlib-graph-in-wxpython